# Set Min Date for iOS in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ios, mobile-safari

I am trying to make a mobile friendly website (for iOS devices) which uses:

```
<input type="date" min="2013-09-01">
```

On iOS, it lets the user select a date before the minimum, is there a different way to set a minimum date, so the date picker does not let the user set a date before the minimum?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using jQueryUI [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/):
And here you can find how to specify min-date: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate